# How can I build ffts for XCode 5?

Tags: ios, xcode, fft

[Anthony Blake](https://github.com/anthonix) published a novel fft approach he calls the [Fastest Fourier Transform in the South](https://github.com/anthonix/ffts), and I'd like to use it in my iOS apps.  He's also a user here on SO, so if he can answer this question, that would be great :)  But if not, maybe another XCode/MacOS guru can point the way to solving the problem.

The issue is described [in this github issue posting here](https://github.com/anthonix/ffts/issues/22).  The short version, as I understand it, is that XCode is trying to build a 64 bit version of the library, but the code itself is 32 bit.  I don't know if the ffts code as its posted there will work as part of a 64 bit app anyway (there's a lot of assembly there, and it's my understanding that assembly has to be hand-tuned to particular processors, and he may not have done such tuning for a 64 bit processor yet).  What I want to know is:

1. How can I compile and use this library as part of an iOS app?
2. If I do so, can I make the app a 32 bit app on a 64 bit iOS device, so that I don't have to worry about compiling both 32 and 64 bit versions?

As a side note, I do believe that this question should be tagged 'ffts' (as 'fftw' is a tag), but meh.

Comment: ffts generates machine code at runtime, and the iOS security sandbox prevents any generated code from running.

Comment: So there's no way to use the ffts on iOS?  That is a damn shame.

Comment: There might be.  But you would have to get FFTS to somehow generate an ARM assembly language file for your selected parameters before compiling an iOS library and/or building an app.

Comment: Well, first, I need to solve the compilation issue, then I guess the next step is to preset a few select sizes and then generate a library for iOS that way.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use the Accelerate framework, unless you measure things and can prove that it isn't fast enough. Apple has some pretty clever people working on these libraries (from personal knowledge, not just an assumption), so beating them in speed, especially on all kinds of different devices, would be quite a challenge.

Comment: An interesting point, but the fact is, if I'm stuck implementing a layer on top of vDSP to use on images captured from the camera (which I have to-- it's beyond my why vDSP forces radix-2 sizes when the camera does not necessarily take square images), I might as well make it fast.  Maybe you can ask these clever people you personally know why I can't have a function to transform a UIImage captured from the camera into real space floats, but instead have to write a whole framework on top of what they've done.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your project's target build settings and and leave only `armv7` as build arhitecture and `armv7 & armv7s` as valid architectures.

This will build your project for both 32bit & 64bit devices but the app will run in 32bit mode.